# Add sheet with a date as a name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a sheet and name it today's date. If the date is already taken, the next following free date.

Macro works for first and second run. When I run it a third time I get an error:

> "Sheet name already exist"

I am using following code.

```
Sub datesheets()

    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim w As Worksheet 

    For Each w In Worksheets
        If w.Name = Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") Then
            found = True
            shname = Format(DateAdd("d", 1, Now()), "dd.mm.yyyy")
            Worksheets.Add(, w).Name = shname
        End If
    Next w

    If found = False Then
        Worksheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The first time you ran the code, there was no `sheet("30.09.2018")` hence `found = false` and you add `sheet("30.09.2018")`. The second time, `found = True` and you add `sheet("01.10.2018")`. Then the third time, `sheet("30.09.2018")` is found and you add `sheet("01.10.2018")` again, so here's the problem.

Comment: There are no big problems with the code, so I think the problem is that what you expected when you ran the third time?

Comment: @newacc2240 I think he wants a new sheet one day further into the future every time he presses the button

Comment: If I were to do it I would loop through each sheet, cdate() the names and keep track of the ‘newest’ date as it went along, then add one for one day after that - unless the newest date is before today I guess

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution. Today's date is declared as biggest date and then compared with sheets to find if there is a sheet with a date bigger than or equal to it. If so the biggerDate is being incremented.

```
Sub addNextDateSheet()

    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim biggestDate As Date

    biggestDate = Date

    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        'checking if the name is date
        If IsDate(Replace(sheet.Name, ".", "/")) Then
            'checking if the name is same as today or bigger
            If CDate(Replace(sheet.Name, ".", "/")) >= biggestDate Then
                'increment date if it is the same or bigger
                biggestDate = CDate(Replace(sheet.Name, ".", "/")) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next sheet

    'add new sheet
    Worksheets.Add(ActiveSheet).Name = Format(biggestDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")

End Sub
```

**Thank you @newacc2240 for your feedback - it was very helpful.**

Comment: I suggest that maybe check `IsDate` first. Not sure that all the worksheets are named after date.

Comment: BTW the `Mid` in your function should be `Mid(sheetName, 4, 2)` instead.

Comment: I did that but dd.mm.yyyy date format, which is the one selected by OP is evaluating to false. That is why I included the on error resume next statement (which I know is a bad practice).

Comment: @newacc2240 thank you for feedback. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: I've wrote a sol just the same logic as yours, I replace `.` with `/` first then check `IsDate`

Comment: Thank you newacc2240 for your feedback and suggestions - I have corrected my answer :)

Comment: @PawelCzyz bro it giving me the same error as "Duplicate Sheet Name Already Exist" same like the macro I shared.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error - what is the date you are getting the error on? What are the sheets name in your workbook?

Comment: @PawelCzyz When I run the code in first click it add sheet with date 30.09.2018. Then When I click for more sheet it add 01.10.2018 as per code instruction. On the next it should add 02.10.2018 but it gives and error of duplicate name of 01.10.2018 instead of add new sheet. Thanks bro this is issue that I am still facing.

Comment: Are you sure you are using code provided by me? It seems that you are using your old code. Please verify. If you want to replace code assigned to a button you should right click it and select assign macro. Try this - given code should not produce that error.

Comment: Sub addNextDateSheet()
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim biggestDate As Date
    biggestDate = Date
    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        If IsDate(Replace(sheet.Name, ".", "/")) Then
            If CDate(Replace(sheet.Name, ".", "/")) >= biggestDate Then
                biggestDate = CDate(Replace(sheet.Name, ".", "/")) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next sheet

    'add new sheet
    Worksheets.Add(ActiveSheet).Name = Format(biggestDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")
End Sub

Comment: But it gives me the same error when run third time.

Comment: Also are you using the button you mentioned earlier or are you running the code straight from the editor? Try this: make a fresh workbook, copy the code and run it few times. Check the result - there should be no error.

Comment: @PawelCzyz I have tried it with new sheet but giving same error as I described above.